# Remove all meta-data from Outlook Email File (MSG)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, metadata, headers

I need to forward an email in Outlook as attachment.

But, the recipient is not supposed to know from whom I received the email in the first place. This, information, plus many more, are visible when opening an Email in Outlook, then clicking, 'File', 'Info', 'Properties', reading under 'Internet headers'.

Actually, I want the receipient to have no metadata at all.

The formating and the attachments of the email need to be preserved.

I could not find a way to remove this 'Internet headers' or any other metadata.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I'm afraid there is no such method to remove all meta-data from Outlook Email File. You may go to Outlook for developers forum for some information.

Answer (score 0):

To remove metadata from Outlook email messages saved in the .msg format, I'm trying a linux program called MetadataCleaner.